# Disable field on hook_form_alter

Tags: 6, forms

I have a form that I want to render with a disabled field.

I've already tried:

```
$form_element['#node']->field_assoc_cnpj[0]['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => 'disabled');
```

And also to use it directly into the `form` array:

```
$form['#node']->field_assoc_cnpj[0]['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => 'disabled');
```

Nothing seems to work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you using that code?

Comment: At the form_alter hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, CCK is yet another module that alters the forms. When your form_alter function is used, even if you disable the field, it will not work. That's because the CCK forms are built after those form alter functions.
Note that this limitation is only for Drupal 6. In Drupal 7, it should work with regular form_alter functions.

I had to do this on a client site. [This page](http://drupal.org/node/357328) from Drupal docs helped me a lot.

See Clive's answer. It's how we do it on regular forms. 
But don't forget that you always can use field permissions which is much more robust than form alters.

Also, note that setting the field's disabled attribute means this field will not be submitted by browser. If you want to get the value back to your site, use read only attribute with some fancy css to make it look like disabled (browser will take care to not allow editing). Chuck Norris can hack the page using Firebug or something to change the content though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`#disabled`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#disabled) FAPI property:

```
$form_element['#node']->field_assoc_cnpj[0]['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

> Disables (greys out) a form input element. Note that disabling a form field doesn't necessarily prevent someone from submitting a value through DOM manipulation. It just tells the browser not to accept input.

Comment: It doesn't work! =/

Comment: The `#disabled` property will work but I've just noticed you're not actually setting it on a form element (anything with a `#` in front of it is a property, so `$form_element['#node']` won't ever be rendered). Presumably this code is in `hook_form_alter()` implementation, in which case `$form->field_assoc_cnpj[0]['#disabled'] = TRUE;` may work

Comment: That's actually what I tried when I said it didnt' work. =/

Answer (score 0):

In D7 you can use this:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'registration_form':
      if(isset($form['email_field'])) {
        $form['email_field']['#required'] = TRUE;
      }
      if(isset($form['count'])) {
        $form['count']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
      }
      $form['#validate'][] = 'YOUR_MODULE_registration_form_validate';
      break;
  }
}
```